# Corona SDK Continuous Integration

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, build-automation, coronasdk

Is it possible to build corona applications from console?
Or how can I automate build process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature isnt yet available on Conora, but there is an ongoing campaign to get Ansca to add it to a future build...

More info:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/02/07/support-command-line-thus-continuous-integration-builds

http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2010/12/20/command-line-building

---

As a follow up several months later...

It appears that Corona's new PRO subscriptions will include this functionality:

From: http://www.coronalabs.com/products/enterprise/

> Automate Your Builds
>
> Corona Builder enhances development efficiency by automating builds, allowing team members to work in the simulator and focus on building extraordinary mobile experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now corona SDK is free with native development options. You can setup your custom build script(scripts that run proper gradle or Xcode build commands) for each platform (Android/iOS) to use in CI platforms like Jenkins